# How do I synchronise a flight schedule with my AnyLogic simulation agents?

Tags: anylogic, event-simulation

I am completely new to AnyLogic.

I am creating an airport simulation. I want to link an excel file with the flight schedule (departure time, check-in desk, gate number) so that the agents follow this flight schedule synchronously, so how do I do this?

The pedSource is linked to selectOutput5 where it will decide which check-in desk to go to according to their flight but unsure how to define the conditions with the excel database linked.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the agents, you assign the parameters from the database. Please refer to this link: https://www.anylogic.com/blog/how-to-video-reading-agent-attributes-from-a-database/

Then you can set your condition in selectOutputOut block, such as `agent.checkInDesk==1`.

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted to clarify, what columns would I need in my excel database? 

I have destination, departure time (date and time), check-in desk, gate, and the number of passengers in my excel sheet.